# Portable bluetooth speakers doesn't connect

Tags: linux-mint, audio, bluetooth

I have problem with connection from laptop to portable bluetooth speakers. I use `Linux Mint 18`. When I open list of bluetooth devices I see my speakers(`Sound Blaster FRee`). But status is `Disconnected`. When I to try change type of connection from `Off` to `On` the button returns to `Off`. What is the problem and how to fix it?

[image]